# Why cant you pass MYSQL functions into prepared PDO statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

In my mind, the following script should work:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET status = ?, date_modified = ?");
$stmt->execute(array(1, 'NOW()'));
```

but when passing `NOW()` into the prepared statement, nothing happens. Replacing `NOW()` with an actual date (i.e. 2010-11-23) works just fine.

I am unable to find explanation online. Any ideas?

## EDIT

Just to further clarify and rid of any confusion in the question, I want to actually pass a variable into the prepared statement HOWEVER, the variable will be set to one of five possible date/time functions for mysql.

e.g.

> $var = 'NOW()';
>
> $var = 'LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),
>   INTERVAL 1 MONTH))';
>
> $var = 'LAST_DAY(CURDATE())';

... and so on...

prepared statement turns into:

```
$stmt->execute(array(1, $var));
```

I know this will return the same NULL results, but I am worried if I simply change the sql statement to:

> UPDATE table SET status = ?,
>   date_modified = $var

I am opening myself to injection?

Comment: Prepared statements are used for **separation** of commands and data. And you cannot undo that separation and get data interpreted as SQL statements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to pass `NOW()` as a parameter as there is no need to do any processing on it, given it is a built in SQL Function, so just include it in the actual query like below.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET status = ?, date_modified = NOW()");
```

Alternatively, you can just set the `date_modified` to a TIMESTAMP field and it will automatically update the `date_modified` field on a SQL Update.

Comment: @Brad - thanks, i already have another timestamp field in the database and the actual call is much more than a NOW() but I'll modify accordingly

Comment: to clarify - i am passing a value $variable because the function can change entirely so im still thinking there "could" be a case for injection?

Comment: Then why did you post that code? You should post the actual code being used, if you are passing it a variable, then show the actual variable you are using (or at least examples of it as `NOW()` will never work like you have it), how you are using `NOW()` in the scenario you posted does not make any sense.

Comment: @Brad F Jacobs - the logic is EXACTLY THE SAME regardless of what function I post when they all relate to time. One function would use NOW(), two other datetime fields would not. the varible is set to equal NOW() or another function so, yes, my code and question still stand as valid.

Comment: @JM4 In the updated version, where does `$var` come from exactly? Is it hardcoded or does it come from an unknown source (POST / COOKIE / GET) ?  If it is hardcoded, you are not vulnerable to SQL Injection. If it comes form an unknown source, well your only other option would be to use some type of validation method to validate it or remove any characters that are not necessary, IE: `'":\/` etc, that you would not expect to see for that query, via regex or similar.

Comment: @Brad - $var's value comes from a series of POST variables, so for example: if $_POST['date_selected'] > date('d'), then $var = 'NOW()'; if $_POST['date_selected'] < date('d'), $var = 'LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))';

Comment: @JM4, Given that you are not actually using the POST data and you are manually setting `$var`, there is no fear for SQL injection to occur.

Answer (score 7):

Prepared statements interpret everything you insert into them as a literal string. This is to prevent any type of unpredictable SQL injection.

What is actually happening is that `NOW()` is attempting to be inserted into the database just as it reads (literally, `NOW()`) instead of getting the actual date to insert. It is then probably showing blank in your database because you have a date column, which doesn't interpret `NOW()` as a date and therefore doesn't accept it.

If possible, you should try to execute the SQL without using any substitution methods as there is nothing dangerous to this approach.

Comment: thanks, see my comment below brad's below. The variable I am 'actually' passing can change and MAY be susceptible to injection still?

Comment: If all of your `$var` values are set within you PHP script and not any external sources, then you don't have to worry about any kind of injection.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that PDO is assuming 'NOW()' is a string and enclosing it in quotes when populating the query parameters.  I would just pass the current date using the PHP function date('Y-m-d'), which will give you the same results.