# PHP PDO::prepare query building - problems with mysql functions

Tags: php, pdo

Related question, but not helpful to me: [Why cant you pass MYSQL functions into prepared PDO statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259274/why-cant-you-pass-mysql-functions-into-prepared-pdo-statements)

Here's the deal: I'm writing an abstraction layer to PHP PDO and implementing a query builder.
This exact problem is occurring only in INSERT statements. Here's an example of my code:

```
$db->insert('table_name')
    ->keys(array('abc', 'def', 'ghi'))
    ->values(array($var1, $var2, $var3)) // can take a 2D array if you want to insert multiple rows at the same time
    ->execute();
```

The underlying code builds the query string with ?'s instead of values. For this particular example the query would result in the following:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`
(`abc`, `def`, `ghi`)
VALUES
(?, ?, ?)
```

Upon calling `execute()`, it passes the values to `PDOStatement::execute()` as single dimension array (i.e. all values associated with the question marks are put in a single array). And this is where the problems start - the `PDOStatement::execute()` does not process MySQL functions as such, but quotes them as strings, thus breaking the query:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`
(`abc`, `def`, `ghi`)
VALUES
('123', 456, 'NOW()') -- error, incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()'
```

The question is - how do I make this work while still maintaining the same interface? I know I could just check if the value of the column is a MySQL function and put it in directly instead of the question mark, but there are many functions one could use there and that would suck.

Edit: so it seems that for now the easiest option would be to simply set the values to leave alone like this: `$var3 => 'noquote'`. It's not really a good one, but it works.

Comment: PDO is already an abstraction. What is your goal in adding yet another layer?

Comment: afaik pdo doesn't have an ->insert statement, it has ->query and ->prepare, so unless you are using another code abstraction, insert() should do nothing at all.

Comment: @Lucas - that insert() is not from PDO, that is a function written by me that returns an object that contains methods related only to MySQL INSERT statements. Same for update() and select().

Comment: @Olaf - reduction of human error would be one reason.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your insert function then.

Comment: @Lucas - my insert function only constructs a new DbInsert object and returns it. It's a different way for doing `$dbi = new DbInsert('tableName'); $dbi->keys(blabla)->values(blabla)->execute();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another argument for that method:

- table name
- values (as associative array)
- sql (as associative array)

Keep in mind, that you cannot use '?' when you want to do access the columns, e. g. in `COLUMN1 + 1` or `COLUMN1 + COLUMN2`.

Answer (score 1):

I procede like that:

```
$bdd->prepare(INSERT INTO `table_name` (`abc`, `def`, `ghi`) VALUES (?, ?, ?))
$bdd->execute(array('abcValue', 'devValue', 'ghiValue'))
```

Comment: It would work if I were to insert only one row (can't automate multiple rows this way), and it would require me to specify manually that col1/col2 are variables and col3 is a MySQL function. So yeah, doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Your last query comes up with an error `( -- error, incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()')`
Try formatting your date like this instead:

`DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))`

Comment: Wrong, it says so because the value is a quoted string, and MySQL functions must be unquoted. I.E. it must be `INSERT INTO .. VALUES ('abc', NOW())`, NOT `INSERT INTO .. VALUES ('abc', 'NOW()')`.